# Can I change video chat provider for Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

As a user of Google Calendar, and having a company based on Google calendars, I would like to be able to change video providers for the default generated video link.

Curent Provider: Google Hangouts

Requested Provider: [Appear.in](https://appear.in/)

Expected Result:
When an event is scheduled, it uses the same logic to append the event name to /appear-in

Why: Google Hangouts has been dropping plenty of conferences recently. No other provider / Skype / Appearin / other / has been experiencing this.

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm afraid not.

Google does not offer a way to change the video conference provider offered by Google Calendar. You'll need to use a different calendar product.